# How to resize the flexslider?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, flexslider

I'm using the following template to build my school website.
http://themes.quitenicestuff.com/parkcollegewp/

They have used the flex slider in their template.But instead of a full size slider I need the size of the slider to be reduced to my header size.

Here is the flexslider.css

```
/* Browser Resets */
.flex-container a:active,
.slider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.slider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;} 

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/
.slider, .slider-blocks, .page-slider {padding: 0;}
.slider .slides > li, .slider-blocks .slides > li, .page-slider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.slider .slides img, .page-slider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.slides:after {content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}
html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;}
* html .slides {height: 1%;}

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you
 * include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}

/* FlexSlider Default Theme
*********************************/
.slider, .slider-blocks, .page-slider { background: transparent; position: relative; zoom: 1;}
.flex-viewport {max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease;}
.slider .slides, .slider-blocks, .page-slider {zoom: 1;}
.carousel li {margin-right: 5px}

/* Direction Nav */
.flex-direction-nav {*height: 0;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {opacity: .3!important; filter:alpha(opacity=30); cursor: default;}

/* Control Nav */
.flex-control-nav {width: 100%; text-align: center;}
.flex-control-nav li {margin: 0 3px; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;}
.flex-control-paging li a {width: 11px; height: 11px; display: block; background: #666; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -o-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover { background: #333; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active { background: #000; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); cursor: default; }

.flex-control-thumbs {margin: 5px 0 0; position: static; overflow: hidden;}
.flex-control-thumbs li {width: 25%; float: left; margin: 0;}
.flex-control-thumbs img {width: 100%; display: block; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {opacity: 1; cursor: default;}
```

Even though I changed the width from 100% to 1000px it doesn't change.What should I do?Please help me.I already posted it in Wordpress forum.But didn't get a single reply.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress, why don't you try meta slider plugins. With that you can decide your own width and height, don't forget to tick off the 100% width on advance settings though.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the height and width of flex slider in the admin panel. In the slider option,   you can give custom width and height of the slider. That basically does the re size. OR you can use WP slider and do as i mentioned. It might solve your issue

Comment: Where in the admin panel can you make these changes? Apparently setting sizes with flexslider is a pretty prevalent issue, there seem to be a lot of unanswered questions to this end.